# Javadoc error while generating files

Tags: java, javadoc

I tried to run the javadoc command and I get the following error while generating the html file. What should i change to be able to produce the documentation.

I've used the Javadoc comments /**   */ in the program. What should I do to fix this error?

```
D:\jdk1.7\bin>javadoc rational.java
Loading source file rational.java...
Constructing Javadoc information...
Standard Doclet version 1.7.0_02
Building tree for all the packages and classes...
Generating \rational.html...
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:202)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$FileLoader.<init>(URLClassPath.java:1016)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:357)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$3.run(URLClassPath.java:352)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:351)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getLoader(URLClassPath.java:328)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.findResource(URLClassPath.java:171)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:551)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$2.run(URLClassLoader.java:549)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findResource(URLClassLoader.java:548)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.getResource(ClassLoader.java:1138)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(URLClassLoader.java:227)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport$4.run(SecuritySupport.java:94)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SecuritySupport.getResourceAsStream(SecuritySupport
.java:87)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.findJarServiceProvider(FactoryFinder.
java:248)
        at javax.xml.parsers.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:221)
        at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory.newInstance(SAXParserFactory.java:
126)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML
(LayoutParser.java:88)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(Cl
assBuilder.java:117)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(Html
Doclet.java:186)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:196)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:180)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration
(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractD
oclet.java:83)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:6
3)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.LayoutParser.parseXML
(LayoutParser.java:95)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.builders.ClassBuilder.build(Cl
assBuilder.java:117)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(Html
Doclet.java:186)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:196)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:180)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration
(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractD
oclet.java:83)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:6
3)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.util.DocletAbortException
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.generateClassFiles(Html
Doclet.java:190)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:196)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.generateClassFi
les(AbstractDoclet.java:180)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.startGeneration
(AbstractDoclet.java:125)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.internal.toolkit.AbstractDoclet.start(AbstractD
oclet.java:83)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.formats.html.HtmlDoclet.start(HtmlDoclet.java:6
3)
        at com.sun.tools.doclets.standard.Standard.start(Standard.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.invoke(DocletInvoker.java:280)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.DocletInvoker.start(DocletInvoker.java:160)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.parseAndExecute(Start.java:397)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Start.begin(Start.java:167)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.execute(Main.java:59)
        at com.sun.tools.javadoc.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

`rational.java` file

```
/**
* Rational number effective representation
* @author  Jash Jacob
*/

public class rational
{

    /** Constructor for class rational  */

    public rational(int numerator,int denominator)
    {
        //some code
    }
   //** gcd() returns the greatest common divisor */
    public static int gcd(int m,int n)
    {   
        //somecode
    }

    /** tostring() function to return the effective representaion */
    public String tostring()
    {
        //somecode
    }

    /** main() function takes the numerator and denominator values from the user */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        //some code

    }
 }
```

Comment: Posting the relevant code (`rational.java`) that is the input would probably help to answer your question.

Comment: @jpw Are you sure it could be a error with the input ?

Comment: No, but it might help to rule out the source as the problem, and other people can test it too and see if they get the same error.

Comment: I've tried generating Javadoc from your code with Java versions 1.6 and 1.8 with no issues (other than Javadoc warnings about missing tags), but I've read somewhere that it can be an issue with the `CLASSPATH` variable pointing to an incorrect version of the `tools.jar`file, so you could try unsetting the CLASSPATH (using `set CLASSPATH=` ).